# sql CONVERT to datetime does not change printed date format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in a table `updatedDate` - which is a `datetime` data type.

Data sample:

```
2017-10-15 18:08:22.000
2017-10-15 18:07:44.000
2017-10-15 18:07:17.000
2017-10-15 18:07:10.000
2017-10-14 18:00:54.000
2017-10-13 17:59:23.000
2017-10-13 17:59:13.000
```

I would like to display a list of DISTINCT dates, in the format of dd/mm/yyyy, but for the life of me... I can't get it. I would think it should be:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT convert(datetime,updatedDate,103)
 FROM [tblStudentCourses] 
 ORDER BY updatedDate DESC
```

But it does not actually convert to the `103` format... it just gives it to me as the full date and time format as originally, without any CONVERT.

What I want to get would be:

```
15/10/2017
14/10/2017
13/10/2017
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're just looking for it to display like that in a select statement, then convert it to varchar(10) instead of datetime.

Comment: but then I get a format of `Oct 15 201` - whereas i need dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: ... `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), updatedDate, 103)` (you need to include the format in the conversion if you want a specific format - and converting to varchar instead of datetime would be what you want for displaying the date)

Comment: Still not - the resulting `ORDER BY` also needs to be converted as you suggested, and then i lose the ability to sort by date i get some odd order like: 31/10/2016, 31/10/2013, 31/08/2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format, you can use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateColumn, 103)`.

To maintain the proper ordering, you can wrap it all in a subquery. For example:

```
SELECT DisplayDate
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        DisplayDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(UpdatedDate AS DATE), 103),
        ActualDate = CAST(UpdatedDate AS DATE)
    FROM [tblStudentCourses] 
) AS T
ORDER BY ActualDate;
```

Note: Cast the date column to date if it's datetime like your sample data.

Comment: @Alex, you do if you only want one column in the select (e.g. the display date and not the actual date). The display date is varchar and therefore orders alphabetically, not by the date...

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT convert(VARCHAR,updatedDate,103)
FROM [tblStudentCourses] 
ORDER BY updatedDate DESC
```

You should use convert to varchar for formating to various date formats

Comment: Thanks, this was suggested, but does not work - see above